# using str.contains to replace part of a string up to a delimiter

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, scikit-learn

you are my last bastion of hope before I turn to the horrid world of excel macros,

I have a humongous data frame from excel that I'm manipulating, Pandas has proved useful for editing as excel really struggles.

My final issue is as follows:

Now, I have a column that lists interests by user with over 100k rows. The problem being that the data was never validated, so I have potentially useful information which i need to manipulate into 1 of 10 outputs.

I've found using `str.replace` and `str.contains` is extremely useful and I think I would build some dicts or lists to iterate through to work the logic.

When I use `str.contains` on my `list` it replaces the whole `string` and I need to keep information after the delimiter to replace (as users can have more than one interest).

so I could have

```
User, Interest 
a     Racing, Football, Soccer, Kickball, footy, Basketball, Hockey, Running, Jogging, Jogging & Running 
b      Racing, Jogging, Basketball, Computers, Reading. 
c     Ice Hockey
```

so for example, there are multiple examples of Football which would need to be put into one category, and so forth.

with the assumption that we are only after sports, what would also be an efficient method to clean the data that is non sport?

I hope the entirety of the my issue makes sense.

Output:

```
User, Interest
a      Race, Ball Sport, Athletics
b      Race, Ball Sport, Athletics
c      Athletics
```

Comment: Filter each line with a set of whitelisted words? A simple example:
`whitelist = ['a', 'b']; line = ['a', 'e', 'f', 'b']; print(list(filter(lambda word: word in whitelist, line)))` But this would not be very efficient.

Comment: Well, as a novice perhaps using "efficient" was not a good choice of words. But thanks, I'll have a read of the white list function!

Comment: I'm not sure how much you want to look into this or if it's worth it, but machine learning can be quite helpful with this type of stuff. Checkout out https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123060/clustering-a-long-list-of-strings-words-into-similarity-groups

Comment: You can set up conditions to replace strings as well using numpy.select

Comment: Why is there no output for `c`?

Comment: Sorry @GregSchmit left that out in my haste, added it in.

Cheers.

Comment: as a linguist that post is extremely interesting bookmarking for my train commute home!  @Chrispresso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you want to clean the file by modifying it, or if you want to selectively filter the interests at runtime, but here is how I would do this:

- First I would get the sorted (and unique) list of all interests: copy all of them in a file, one per line, and run some `sort -u FILE > OUTPUT` in Bash or else.
- Then I would regroup the interests (Racing and Race => Race)
- With these groups, I would create a mapping with a dictionary in Python:

  ```
  mapping = {
      'racing': 'Race',
      'race': 'Race',
      'football': 'Ball Sport',
      ...
  }
  ```
- Finally, when reading the file, I would use a function to return the validated interests for each line:

  ```
  def validate_interests(*interests):
      validated = []
      for interest in interests:
          valid = mapping.get(interest.lower(), None)
          if valid is not None:
              validated.append(valid)
      return validated


  In [10]: validate_interests('Football', 'Racing')
  Out[10]: ['Ball Sport', 'Race']
  ```

Of course you would need to iterate on the lines and parse them into a list of interests, but I won't go too much into details.

Comment: This is extremely helpful, would you recommend this method for potentially thousands of variants?

Comment: Well, it's a personal opinion, but if you do it once and it is working, then you can go to the next step and automate it! Sorting with unique items in Python is easy, the problem is the grouping part: you might need machine learning here as said in a previous comment.

Comment: the scikitlearn module looks interesting, I'll go away and try to answer my own question in a few days!

thanks for your help buddy!

Comment: after much pain, I had succumbed and did this piece of work manually. Reading journals regarding segmentation and clustering was extremely interesting. I understand the theory but the application is still beyond my skill set.